# INNER JOIN with NOT IN returns wrong results

Tags: mysql

I have a table `product` with fields such as `title` (varchar) or `availability` (bool).

The user can search for products by name (`product.title`), but can also apply certain filters (such as type, producer, etc.).
I solved this using `SELECT` alongside `INNER JOIN`. An example of a generated query looks like this:

```
SELECT z.* 
FROM product z 
WHERE (z.title LIKE "%bread%") 
AND z.availability = 1 
AND z.category IN (4,5,6);
```

This works perfectly well. However, products also are tagged with "allergy tags" (such as *gluten*).
Unfortunately, a product can hold any number of "allergy tags", thus i needed to use a crosslinking table (`crosslink__productXproduct_allergy_tag`):

```
id int not null primary key auto_increment
productId int
allergyTagID int
```

The tags are stored in table `product_allergy_tag`, using an id as primary key, and a title for the tag.
Naturally, when searching for products that are gluten-free, the generated query would then look like this:

```
SELECT z.* 
FROM product z  
INNER JOIN crosslink__productXproduct_allergy_tag a ON z.id = a.productId  
WHERE (z.title LIKE "%bread%")
AND z.availability = 1  
AND a.allergyTagId IN (15)
```

(With 15 being the ID of the gluten tag).

However, if i ran the search in the same manner as shown above, a search for gluten-free products would end up showing **only** products that *contain* gluten.

So I figured: I simply need to reverse the logic:

Instead of:

```
a.allergyTagId IN (15)
```

it would be:

```
a.allergyTagId NOT IN (15)
```

Yet however, for reasons I do not understand, the query still returns some products with that allergy tag, although it does not return all of them.

I tried to get to the core of this by testing various options and comparing results, but to no avail.

Rumor has it, I am not an SQL wiz.

Any support on the matter would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Your query returns all products for which an allergen exists that is not gluten. This will not return anything without any allergens, it will return products with multiple allergens more than once, and it will still return gluten products if they also have a second (or third) allergen.

Comment: Since you're  doing an inner join on crosslink__productXproduct_allergy_tag. You are selecting from a table of products with some kind of allergen. You are then narrowing down to those with 'bread' in the title, available and that the allergy isn't gluten. Since some products can have multiple allergens you essentially join on a random allegen of a product, often this wont be gluten and so it'll be selected. Clearly this is completely backwards from what you need. I'd suggest starting again, making logical joins and considering the effect of each addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, the way a join works, it will join it with every match, so you'd get:

Product A - Allergen A
Product A - Allergen B
Product B - Allergen C

You also aren't getting any products that have NO allergens, since the INNER JOIN requires at least one allergen to be selected.

What you want is a JOIN and test that the allergen is NULL. Something like:

```
SELECT z.* FROM product z LEFT JOIN crosslink__productXproduct_allergy_tag a
  ON z.id = a.productId AND a.allergyTagId IN (15) WHERE (z.title LIKE 
 "%bread%") AND z.availability = 1 AND a.allergyTagId IS NULL
```

This does the allergen check at the time of the JOIN. If there are matches, it will include a row for each match with the allergyTagId set to the ID that matched, and if it doesn't match any, it will have NULL in that column. Then, filter on the NULL column to get products that don't hit on any allergens.

Comment: At first it made sense to me, but looking into it i understand that it does not account for excluding the selected allergy tags? Also, it seems to query for entries that have an allergy tag id set AND where the allergy tag id is null. It would not return anything at all?

Comment: @SquareCat the query is valid when you understand the semantics:  `t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ... WHERE t2.c1 IS NULL` means "only include rows from t1 where the left join did not find a matching row in t2."  We aren't looking for nulls *in* t2, we're looking for nulls in *the joinable row* in t2... which is true only when no rows contain the value we want to prove does not exist, as long as t2.c1 is not a billable column... which is exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Logically equivalent to this answer, and perhaps more intuitive: `SELECT z.* FROM product z WHERE (z.title LIKE 
 "%bread%") AND z.availability = 1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM crosslink__productXproduct_allergy_tag a 
 WHERE  a.productId = z.id AND a.allergyTagId IN (15));`

Comment: *nullable column, 2 comments above, not "billable column." (autocorrect fail)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT z.* FROM product z where z.title like "%bread%" and z.availability = 1 and z.id not in (Select productId from crosslink__productXproduct_allergy_tag a where a.allergyTagId = 15)
```

Edit: What you want is the list of products excluding those in the list of products with allergytag of 15. The subquery finds the list of products with an allergytag of 15, and the primary query selects all of the ones that aren't those.